# Gazebo not running when I try to load STL files

Tags: control, ros, gazebo, ros2, urdf

I have an issue with Gazebo, when I try to load my URDF file (including STL meshes), Gazebo crashes.

This is my URDF file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <robot name="robot">
  <link name="world"/>
  <link name="base_link">
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.032 0.22 0.042"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <geometry>
               <mesh filename="package://hexapod_rviz/meshes/Body.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="3.14 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.18"/>
      </visual>
    <inertial>
    <mass value="0.00001"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.0" izz="0.1" />
    </inertial>
  </link>


    <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <dynamics damping="10" friction="1.0"/>

  </joint>


</robot>
```

I am using Gazebo11.0 with ROS 2 Humble.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Hi @user35808 welcome to *Robotics*. Reading your question there's not enough context to really help answer your question. There's many different ways that things could go wrong. The specific error message that you're getting is important, in addition please provide enough information to reproduce your problem quickly so that people can help you best. Otherwise people will just be guessing about what's going on on your system. So to that end please edit your question to provide more details about what's going on on your system so that people here can effectively help you.

Comment: Does this work if you remove just the `<geometry>` section? I don't know if all the `inertia` values need to be specified or not, but I do see that you're only passing 6 of the 9 values.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. i try to remove <geometry> and it still don't work. i think the matrix of inertia is symetric and that's why i pass only 6 values (Ixy=Iyx,.....)
i think the problem is that my gazebo don't load my stl files

Comment: it should read STL files, check this file https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/common/STLLoader.cc

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when it works, you will be able to play with path. I use yhis approach in examples on [robotics.snowcron.com](https://robotics.snowcron.com). Note that (just like in your case) I gave up trying to figure the pervasive logic of ROS2 working with path simplifications, and use "file" instead, but when used with "find" it is not that ugly after all:

```
<link name="base_0">
    <inertial>
        <mass value="3.635"/>
        <origin xyz="4e-06   -0.001     0.082"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.02216" ixy="5.8e-06" ixz="6.2e-06" iyy="0.02"
            iyz="-5.3e-05"
            izz="0.02"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_03)/description/meshes/armA/armA_0.stl" 
                scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="gray">
            <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
        </material>                  
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_03)/description/meshes/armA/armA_0.stl" 
                scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
</link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more context on the error, please consider adding the error or trace you're getting.
To debug, I would go about the following ways:

- Check if the package is correctly installed/located, `ros2 pkg list | grep hexapod_rviz`
- Check if the URDF model loads correctly, `xacro <package_path>/model.urdf`. You can also try updating the verbosity level to show warnings/errors.
- Use absolute file:// paths instead of package:// and see it loads up.

Hope any of these helps narrow down your issue!